# Find the restrictions on the angles $\theta$ and $\varphi$ to the spherical surface $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=4$, z≥1

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, surface-integrals

I have a portion of a sphere defined by $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=4$,  z ≥ 1, and want to change into spherical coordinates and compute the area of over the surface. For this I need to find the restrictions on the angles $\theta$ and $\varphi$. I know that the radius of the sphere is 2, and the the projection onto the xy plane gives a circle with radius $\sqrt3$.

I am having a hard time imaging in geometrically, how can I find the restrictions on the angles? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given radius of the sphere is $2$, its surface can be parametrized in spherical coordinates as,

$x = 2 \cos \theta \sin\phi, y = 2 \sin \theta \sin \phi, z = 2 \cos \phi$

As we need to find surface area of the sphere for $z \geq 1$,

$\cos \phi \geq \frac{1}{2} \implies \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$.

So limits of double integral to find surface area are $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and $0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! How did you write the condition cos $\varphi$ ≥ 1/2, i.e. why is it that inequality?

Comment: From $z = 2 \cos\phi \geq 1$. The question says $z \geq 1$.

Comment: Also I hope you are clear on the integral to find surface area which will be $4 \sin \phi \ d\phi \ d\theta$.

Comment: yes I am! Thanks so much for the help